# LIKE with or without wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this situation:

```
CREATE TABLE ProvaSrl
    (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Ragsoc varchar(20))

INSERT ProvaSrl VALUES ('pippo spa'),
                       ('pluto srl'),
                       ('paperino s.r.l'),
                       ('minnie S.R.L'),
                       ('topolino SRL')

SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl
WHERE ragsoc LIKE
```

I want find all the records that have `s.r.l`, `srl`, `SRL` or `S.R.L` in the `RagSoc` column. I have case insensitive database.

Can I use the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: BTW - "caratteri jolly" is *usually* translated as "wildcards". I took the liberty of adding it in the title & adding the relevant tag

Comment: @TobiaTesan While it's OK to swap "jolly" with "wild", you should not change the names of tables, values etc.

Comment: What about "SR.L" or "SrL"?

Comment: @DavidG: I thought that "italian cartoon character names -> original cartoon character names" and "prova" -> "test" would have made the post *more* readable for non-italian speakers without significant loss for italian speakers. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thaks Tobia, I like your correction

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl WHERE ragsoc LIKE  '%s.r.l%'
union
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl WHERE ragsoc LIKE  '%srl%'
union
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl WHERE ragsoc LIKE  '%S.R.L%'
```

Comment: Why not OR those three LIKE's instead?

Comment: yes ...we can or this will be better..SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl WHERE ragsoc LIKE any (  '%s.r.l%','%srl%','%SRL%','%S.R.L%');

Comment: WHERE ragsoc LIKE  '%s.r.l%' or ragsoc LIKE  '%srl%' or ragsoc LIKE  '%S.R.L%'

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from dbo.ProvaSrl
where ragsoc like '%s.r.l%'
   or ragsoc like '%srl%'
```

No need to do `LIKE` for both upper and lower case, since the column is said to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I'd drop the trailing `%` as it will always end with it.

Comment: Perhaps that's true. I'll let OP decide if trailing % is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProvaSrl
WHERE upper(ragsoc) LIKE '%S.R.L%'
   OR upper(ragsoc) LIKE '%SRL%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want those specific strings, use `or`:

```
select p.*
from dbo.ProvaSrl
where ragsoc COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like '%s.r.l' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS or
      ragsoc COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like '%srl' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS or
      ragsoc COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like '%SRL' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS or
      ragsoc COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS like 'S.R.L.' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ;
```

I am guessing you just want to look at the end of the `ragsoc` column.  If they can appear anywhere, add an additional wildcard at the end of the pattern.

This uses case sensitive collations to exactly match the four strings mentioned in the question.